# Executing/opening a file using PyQT?

Tags: file, pyqt, pyqt4

I wanted to execute/open an .exe file from within the program I'm writing.Now the PyQT Designer is meant only for the GUI but how to associate a file to the particular UI element that I wish the user to click on,and view the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can open it using `subprocess` module in python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('path/to/exe/file')
```

This will launch the exe file

Comment: Thanks for your method,but subprocess asked for an executable file,and mine was a python script(couldn't get the py2exe to work properly with pyQT) hence I found an alternate solution.